# Using GDataXML to Parse Included XML File

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, parsing, gdata

This XML will be included in the app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>

    <title>Directory</title>
    <description>Directory of Members</description>
    <language>en</language>
    <item>
        <LastName></LastName>
        <FirstName></FirstName>
        <Address></Address>
        <Phone></Phone>
        <Email></Email>
    </item>
    <item>
        <LastName></LastName>
        <FirstName></FirstName>
        <Address></Address>
        <Phone></Phone>
        <Email></Email>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I would like to be able to parse the XML and store into an RSSEntry Class that I have done before with other XMLs.  The issue is that the only other XMLs I have worked with have been located online, and I use ASIHttpRequest Classes as part of the method, and am unsure how to go about changing the code to make it fit.  I currently use this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];   
self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
self.queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
self.feeds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://316apps.com/LakesideNews/feed/",
              nil];   
NSLog(@"%@", self.feeds);

   [self refresh];    
}
- (void)refresh {

for (NSString *feed in _feeds) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:feed];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [_queue addOperation:request];
}

}
- (void)parseRss:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {            

    NSString *blogTitle = [channel valueForChild:@"title"];                    

    NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {
        NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
        NSString *articleUrl = [item valueForChild:@"guid"];            
        NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];        
        NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
        NSString *articleImage = [item valueForChild:@"content:encoded"];
        RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle 
                                                  articleTitle:articleTitle 
                                                    articleUrl:articleUrl 
                                                   articleDate:articleDate
                                                  articleImage:articleImage] autorelease];


        [entries addObject:entry];
    }      
}

}
- (void)parseFeed:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

if ([rootElement.name compare:@"rss"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    [self parseRss:rootElement entries:entries];
} else if ([rootElement.name compare:@"feed"] == NSOrderedSame) {                       
    [self parseAtom:rootElement entries:entries];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unsupported root element: %@", rootElement.name);
}    
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

[_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{

    NSError *error;
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[request responseData] 
                                                           options:0 error:&error];
    if (doc == nil) { 
        NSLog(@"Failed to parse %@", request.url);
    } else {

        NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self parseFeed:doc.rootElement entries:entries];                

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

            for (RSSEntry *entry in entries) {

                int insertIdx = [_allEntries indexForInsertingObject:entry sortedUsingBlock:^(id a, id b) {
                    RSSEntry *entry1 = (RSSEntry *) a;
                    RSSEntry *entry2 = (RSSEntry *) b;
                    return [entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];
                }];

                [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]]
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

            }                            

        }];

    }        
}];

}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
NSError *error = [request error];
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
[self refresh];
}
```

I know to change all the areas for Title to things like Family name, etc., I just don't know how to go about getting the GDataXML to begin parsing the nested XML.

Answer (score 0):

Ray Wenderlich has a fantastic tutorial covering exactly what you are doing. I would start there. [Here's the link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial).

Comment: That's the tutorial I had used in past, but it covers XMLs that are located online, not ones that are nested in the mainBundle

Comment: You could access XMLs from the bundle by using `NSURL *MyURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"yourLocalFile" withExtension:@"xml"];`

Comment: And then just sub-in *MyURL for the address object given in the viewDidLoad self.feeds code?

Comment: So turns out it might not work. But I can point you to another of Ray's classics: http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml In that check out the method `+ (Party *)loadParty`. That method has code to create a GDataXML object from local file.

Comment: Ill check it out, just seems weird that the code to parse an XML already in the app is more of a pain than one that is online only.

Comment: Not actually. Parsing the XML online requires you to add a whole new package (ASIHTTPRequest in this case) and implement error-handling and network management. Parsing local files ensures immediate availability of the resource and also allows you an almost error-free implementation.

Comment: The thing that I liked about the XML being online is that the RSSEntry Class would store all the different items easily.